# dimension of the morphisme of two characters

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I am new to character theory and I have the following question.

In the dual group of a groupe $G$ we can define an inner product. This inner product is equal to :

$$\dim Hom_G(a,b) $$

The problem is that I don’t understand what it means. I know that the dimension of a representation $p : G \to GL(V)$ is equal to $\dim(V)$. So here in the dual group very element has dimension $1$ (since $V = \mathbb{C}^*$).

Yet, here what does it mean to take the dimension of a morphisme between two representations ?

Thanks you !

Comment: Do you know [the projections formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_finite_groups#Decompositions) (also [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maschke%27s_theorem#Module-theoretic)) ? $f\in Hom_G(a,b)$ is "project $a$ on one of its subrepresentation then embed as a subrepresentation of $b$".

Comment: $\operatorname{dim}\operatorname{Hom}_{G}(a,b)$ is the vector space dimension of the $\mathbb{C}$ vector space of linear maps from the representation $a$ to the representation $b$ that respect the action of $G$. A linear map between two representations is a map of the modules given by the representations.